# How did this PEPE dev manage to get his contract address to end in "42069"?

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, etherscan

Have noticed the trend among a few shtcoin devs of customizing the last digits of your erc20 contract address. Here is an example of one of the tokens (ending in 42069) and for a PEPE coin nonetheless cannot be a coincidence. https://etherscan.io/token/0x69D29F1b0cC37d8d3B61583c99Ad0ab926142069.

This ones had me stumped, can anyone share any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

A contract address is deterministic and derived from the deployer address + transaction nonce.

You can brute force any contract address you want by varying your private key, which gives a different deployer address. These are called "vanity addresses."